# What is the probability of measuring in the following circuit?

Tags: ibm-q-experience, measurement, quantum-circuit

[image: Quantum circuit]

So given the circuit and $|\psi\rangle = \alpha|0\rangle + \beta|1\rangle$ above I would like to see what the probabilities of each possible measurement are.

To do this I tried expanding the circuit as follows:

1. after first Hadammard and CNOT we get $(\alpha|0\rangle+ \beta|1\rangle) \otimes \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|00\rangle \otimes |11\rangle)$
2. Then we apply the second CNOT to get: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(CNOT \otimes I)(\alpha|000\rangle + \alpha|011\rangle + \beta|100\rangle + \beta|111\rangle) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\alpha|000\rangle + \alpha|011\rangle + \beta|110\rangle + \beta|101\rangle)$
3. Now apply the final Hadamard to get: $(H\otimes H \otimes I)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\alpha|000\rangle + \alpha|011\rangle + \beta|110\rangle + \beta|101\rangle) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\alpha|+00\rangle + \alpha|+11\rangle + \beta|-10\rangle + \beta|-01\rangle) = \frac{1}{2}(\alpha|000\rangle + \alpha|100\rangle + \alpha|011\rangle + \alpha |111\rangle + \beta|010\rangle - \beta|110\rangle + \beta|001\rangle - \beta|101\rangle)$

So now we have $Pr[000]=Pr[011]=Pr[111] = \frac{1}{4}\alpha^2, Pr[010]=Pr[001]=Pr[110]=Pr[101] = \frac{1}{4}\beta^2$

So now if we measure $00$ on the first two qubits:

$Pr[00] = Pr[000] + Pr[001] = \frac{1}{4}$.

And by similar logic $Pr[11]=PR[01]=Pr[10]=\frac{1}{4}$

But then when I implement this circuit in [IBM quantum](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/composer/files/new?initial=N4IgdghgtgpiBcICyBPAwgSwE4GMCuGALiADQgCOEAzlAiAPIAKAogHICKAggMpIAEAJgB0ABgDcAHTAYwOADZ4AJjD4SKMORgBGARiEycayWCnksMAOZ8IAbQDMAXWM5zVgPZ5CNgU6kALaxsdX1kAD0DgkkCfZ3DbEQco22DjDEUIkNhqPHMMvgBaAD4%2BDy8E4wD4zJhs3KqC4tKbctIQZSoXDAAHQgw3MDoQAF8gA)  I get that probability of $|10\rangle,|11\rangle$ is $0$ so I'm not sure what I did wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Your computations are correct. If you look at the circuit you're creating, you can see the following:

[image]

In particular, note the `0` at the bottom of your measurements. This means **that both measurements are stored within the first bit of the result**. Thus, the last bit will always be `0`, since it stored no measurement. This also explains why you're seeing `00` and `10` with equal probability: the first qubit indeed has $50\%$ chance of being in state $|0\rangle$ and $50\%$ chance of being in state $|1\rangle$.

Thus, in order to get the correct result, be sure not to put the measurement on the same wire when placing them. It should look like this:

[image]

The order of the measurements can be reversed, the only important thing is that they mustn't be stored on the same classical bit. With this circuit, I get the following probabilities:

[image]

Which is what we expect.